# Using Ember.js with Sock.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, sockjs

Is there any tutorial on how to use Sock.js with Ember.js? I can't find any. Any example, tutorial or guide would be nice.
I can use sock.js in plain js like:

```
var sock = new SockJS('/echo');
sock.onmessage = function(e){
    console.log(e.data);
}
sendButton.onclick = function() {
    var text = field.value;
    sock.send(text);
}
```

But don't know how to use it with Ember.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ember you'd probably want to have a high level controller/route that sets up the sock.  Then when a message comes in, assuming that the `data` property of the message is the JSON representation of a model you can use `push` on the `store`.  Something like this should do it:

```
App.Message = DS.Model.extend({...});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController : function(controller, model){
    var sock = new SockJS('/echo');
    var store = this.get('store');
    sock.onmessage = function(e){
      store.push('message',e.data);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: what should i do when i have to call `sock.send()` inside the controller?

Comment: I created the sock instance in App `App.sock = new SockJS("/echo")` inside the Route used App.sock.onmessage. And when I have to send something to server I used `App.sock.send(jsonString)` is it bad? Is there better way?

Comment: I think that should be fine.